# GeoPath to list of coordinates

Tags: geography, geodesy

I'm trying to interpolate a GeoPath to an n-size list of GeoPositions. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on this seemingly common operation anywhere. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out. It's a combination of using GeoDirection and GeoDistance to get the GeoDisplacement, then GeoDestination to get the final lat/lon:

```
dir = GeoDirection[{lat1,lon1}, {lat2,lon2}];
dist = GeoDistance[{lat1,lon1}, {lat2,lon2}];
GeoDestination[GeoPosition[{lat1,lon1}, GeoDisplacement[{dist/2, dir}]]
```

This will give the point half way between {lat1,lon1} and {lat2,lon2}